# Admin menu link visible to authenticated user

Tags: navigation

I am using drupal 7 and i have two types of users for my site: The administrator and the authenticated user.

I want to display to the authenticated user a link in the admin menu sidebar, to see all the content (from a view that i created).

I have created a link in the management menu, called "Show content". As admin, I can see this link but not as authenticated user. Also, I have installed the module "Menu item visibility" and for this menu item i selected the option "authenticated user".  But it is not appearing in the admin menu sidebar for the authenticated user.

So my question is: How can i display an admin menu link for authenticated user?

Comment: In your View, in "Page parameters" section, what is configured in "Access"?

Comment: What do you mean by "admin menu SIDEBAR"? Do you mean the black topbar admin menu that the administrator uses? Can your authenticated user see this black bar at all, or see ANY menu item in it? Have you granted permission to "Access administration menu" to your authenticated user in admin/people/permissions/?

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong. You have a sidebar (region) that you are using only to show menus for the admins. Inside one of these menus you added a link that you want visible to authenticated users too?

Comment: @ Djouuuuh : I changed the access for my view to "Role" and " authenticated user", but the menu link doesn't appear

Comment: @ argiepiano: My authenticated user can see the black toolbar, which includes the option "Add content" and "Log out". Here, i want to add the option to see the overall content. I don't want to give access to the overall administration menu...

Comment: @  Astrayus: Yes, exactly this. I have a sidebar for the admins and another sidebar for the authenticated user. I want to add a link in the sidebar for the authenticated users.